# To get the sitecore username who created sitepage

Tags: sitecore

How to get details which user created the sitepage in Sitecore using Powershell script?

I tried to get which user created the sitepage but I am not getting the sitecore username instead of getting sitepage created date using Sitecore Powershell script. I tried below line in the script

```bash
$createdBy = $sitepage.Created
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find who created an item using the following code snippet:

```
$item.Statistics.CreatedBy
```